# What word could I use to describe singular defects of a surface?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

My master's thesis topic is about automatically detecting defects on wood surfaces.

Whereas most research in the field is concerned about "regular" defects created by processes (such as sawtooth marks, undersanded spots, etc.), I'm specifically interested in "singular" defects. By that, I mean defects that don't repeat, like dents and scratches caused by mishandling or accidently hitting the surface with a tool.

These are fairly large defects that aren't caused by the wood itself (like knots) or any of the work that was done to it. They each have their own separate origin and appearance. In a way, they give a similar vibe to the lonely mountain from the Hobbit novels: they "stand out" on the surface of the wood (planet) and aren't connected or related to other defects (mountains).

I've thought of words like *unusual*, *extraordinary* or *anomalous*, but these aren't correct since my defects aren't necessarily a rare occurance. *Singular*, *particular*, and *independent* are a bit better but they don't feel quite right. *Salient* is the closest I can think of, but it feels like there's a better term.

I'm looking for an adjective or word that can properly describe this type of defect, or perhaps two adjectives that can make the distinction between the two types more obvious.

Comment: Spanish has contributed the perfect word, which unfortunately is also a curse word and vulgar anatomical term in Mexican Spanish. But it was years before I learned what it meant in Spanish.

Comment: Are they contact defects?  Vs. natural variations (knots and the like).

Comment: Are you using 'regular' in the American sense of 'normal', common' or 'standard' or are you using it to mean 'recurrent' or 'periodical'. For example are you using it as in "I'd like a regular coffee not a large one" or as in "The power saw left a regular pattern in the wood"?

Comment: @Xanne Yes, contact defects. My research assumes that the raw wood has been selected to be free of natural defects.

Comment: @BoldBen Both? I think? It's regular in the sense that they repeat, but also in the sense that they are commonly talked about.

Comment: Hello, JS. 'These are fairly large defects that aren't caused by the wood itself (like knots) or any of the work that was done to it. ' What _does_ give rise to them? Subsequent mishandling? (Note that when you use the broadened sense of '[not] "caused" by the wood itself', you necessarily point to an outside agency.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, subsequent mishandling is the cause. Things like accidentally scratching the wood on the edge of a counter or dropping a screwdriver onto it.

Comment: It looks like 'faults caused by subsequent mishandling' is the true category then, not 'irregular / random / isolated ... defects'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, yes... but I'm looking for a term that is a bit shorter to use in the text.

Comment: The snag is that this easily introduces a classification error: << Faults which are (a) specimen-related / (b) manufacturing process-related / (c) 'irregular / random' .... >> Not good.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point. That being said my research assumes that (a) have been eliminated by selecting the raw material, and (b) by sufficient sanding. Since (c) defects are the only ones that remain at that point, we aren't trying to differenciate between the types, only to detect them. I need to make the distinction because there is a significant body of work for detecting (a) and (b), but not for (c).

Comment: You might as well use 'type C defects'.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.woodworkingnetwork.com/best-practices-guide/solid-wood-machining/understanding-working-wood-defects natural versus artificial/mechanical defects. If not those then: **Other**

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One description is **random** defects.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/random)
> Random: adjective:
> happening, done, or chosen by chance rather than according to a plan or pattern

These are random blemishes, random imperfections, or random flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [irregular](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/irregular)?

> without symmetry, even shape, formal arrangement, etc.:
> an irregular pattern.

This would also clearly contrast them with the "regular" defects.

Comment: Hello, Will. No; this will default to the 'irregularly shaped' sense, and choosing it violates the Ross constraint asking for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**unique** (adj.)

> Being the only one of its kind; unlike anything else.
>
> *She used her skills as a graphic artist to create unusual images to give each a **unique** look.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unique)

---

> Tool marks are of two different types: impressed and striated.
> Impressed tool marks results when a tool leaves an impression on
> another surface. **An example would be the result of a blow from a
> hammer on soft wood.** ...
>
> Tool identification is based on the fact that a particular tool will
> leave behind random/**unique marks** that only it could have made. [A.
> Mozayani and C. Noziglia; *The Forensic Laboratory Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Forensic_Laboratory_Handbook/cMDCCCGc18EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=tools%20leave%20unique%20marks%20on%20wood&pg=PA144&printsec=frontcover)
> (2007)

> It's the small knots and other natural characteristics that make each
> wood piece **unique** and allow it to 'speak.' [Joseph Carroll; *The
> Perfect Home*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Perfect_Home/67JlkQljE_gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=makes%20each%20wooden%20piece%20unique&dq=makes%20each%20wooden%20piece%20unique&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> Still, we might be able to pick up some other **unique identifiers**;
> dents, scratches, a dealership decal if we're lucky. [Joel Barrows;
> *Deep Green Cover*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Deep_Green_Cover/wne9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22unique%20dents%20scratches&pg=PT108&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> Every firearm has individual characteristics—much like DNA or
> fingerprints—that leave **unique markings** on every bullet and casing
> that passes through it when fired.
> ...
> Those **scratch
> patterns,** which are **unique** to each gun, are then used to
> compare bullet against bullet. [Kären Hess et al.;
> *Criminal Investigation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Criminal_Investigation/bpNaEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22unique%22%20scratch%20pattern&pg=PA182&printsec=frontcover) (2022)

Answer (score 1):

How about an **uncorrelated** defect for  a mark on tbe surface which cannot be associated with another mark (as part of a pattern), or with an external instrument that could have caused it.

The adjectives suggested in the other answers (unique, random, etc.) are general discriptions of state. However, an adjective related to the process of classifiying the defect might carry the OP’s meaning more clearly.

For example, if a mountain has not yet been climbed, we refer to it as *unclimbed* or *unscaled*.